# Module '"next"' has no exported member 'NextApiRequest' in Next.js version ^12.1.16

Tags: typescript, types, next.js

When trying to type the request/response object of your Next.js APIs for versions `>= 12.1.16`, either of the following errors shows up:

```
Module '"next"' has no exported member 'NextApiRequest'.
```

or

```
Module '"next"' has no exported member 'NextApiResponse'.
```

This wasn't an issue in versions `< 12.1.16` but they are now.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To fix this, you simply need to import from the `next/types` module for versions of `Next.js > 12.1.16`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next/types";
```

Intellisense may help you figure this out, but if it doesn't, you can look in the `next/types/index.d.ts` file. Insofar as you initialized your project with TypeScript, Next.js will provide its own types and they can all be found in that file - every type import will be from that path.

By the time I asked and answered this question, I couldn't find anything about it in the official documentation.

Comment: Using the documented example for API routes has this message. The example works, but your update to `next/types` helped get rid of the message. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes